# Can I get data from custom adapter with clicking on a check box inside the adapter's item?

Tags: android, android-studio, checkbox, android-adapter

I don't want to click on the item of the adapter(`OnItemClickListener`),I only want to check the checkbox that in the item and if it's checked, get the data from this item.

Answer (score 0):

Is checkbox in ListView? İf checkbox in ListView, you can use this code:

```
@Override    
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    CheckBox checkB=(CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.your_checkbox_id);
    if(checkB.isChecked()){
      //you can get data from here
      //for example: checkB.getText();
    }
}
```